# run php script after every 100ms

Tags: php

Is it possible to run a php script after every 100ms ? This script will check a database for changes and then the changes will be reflected into some other database. I am already doing it using Triggers. But I want to know if there is any other way to do it without using Cron and Triggers. I will be using Linux for this purpose.
Thanks

Comment: ...wouldn't you be spending more time starting up the interpreter than actually running anything?  Better to just have a script that sleeps til it's time to run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running something every 100ms almost means that it runs all the time , might as well create a daemon that continuously loops and executes

or use triggers. Essentially on every database change it will copy to another table/db.

http://codespatter.com/2008/05/06/how-to-use-triggers-to-track-changes-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this with cron (it has a max frequency of one minute) and this is a really bad idea. You will be running a whole new php interpreter ten times per second, not to mention doing database connection too.

Far better perhaps would be to run one program that re-uses it's connection and checks every second or so.

Sounds a little like you are trying to make your own database replication or sync between two databases.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a daemon to do it, essentially a script which continually runs in memory somewhere to then run whatever code you want to.

So that daemon would then do the database processing for you, and you wouldn't have to call a script over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Use your favorite programming language and set up a permanent loop to run it every 100ms, then put the script into inittab with 'respawn' (man inittab for complete syntax). Finally, `init q` to reload init.

Answer (score 1):

It's best if you write a little daemon for that. Use the [`pcntl`](http://php.net/pcntl) functions to do so. In your case you might get away with:

```
<?php

   while (1) {
        usleep(100000);

        if (pcntl_fork() == 0) {
             include("/lib/100ms-script.php");
             exit;
        }
        // else pcntl_wait(); eventually
   }
```

Comment: You should remember to clean up zombie processes when you're forking using pcntl_waitpid() or the related, so the code would be a bit more complex than that...and be careful when forking because you can easily mess up and spawn so many children the server bogs down. But I'm on board with that idea.

Comment: Yes, it will end up needing a lot more utility code (also to prevent the daemon from being started twice itself). So probably easier to try something like http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon for it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that this is in reference to some type of web page to be created. If so, this sounds like this is a job for Ajax, not PHP. As you may already know PHP processing is done on the server side. Once processing is complete the page is served up to the client.

With Ajax/JavaScript processing can continue via the browser. You can setup a timer that can then be used to communicate with the server. Depending on the output of the response the page may be updated to reflect the necessary changes.

Comment: ajax has nothing to do with direct access to a database.